# Possible bug with ActionFilterAttribute in Orchard 1.8

Tags: asynchronous, filter, orchardcms, asp.net-web-api, orchardcms-1.8

So, we have been looking at creating an IApiFilter to do some pre and post information logging but we have come across an issue that looks to be a bug.

We created a class that extends the ActionFilterAttribute (System.Web.HttpFilters) and, long story short, left it's contents blank so that is merely inherited from it's base class:

```
public class ApiLoggingFilter : ActionFilterAttribute, IApiFilterProvider
{
}
```

When debugging we hit the OrchardApiActionFilterDispatcher (Orchard.WebApi.Filters) and the filter dispatches to `actionFilter.ExecuteActionFilterAsync(...)`

This shortly results in a StackOverflowException and since we have nothing new in our Filter, the issue must lie with the interaction between the dispatcher and the filter.

Whilst investigating this we came up with a couple of things pertinent. We also tried creating a class that extended `ExceptionFilterAttribute` and this functioned successfully.
Digging into this area, we found a key difference between the two. `IExceptionFilter` (which `ExceptionFilterAttribute` implements) has the following signature on it:

```
Task ExecuteExceptionFilterAsync(
    HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext,
    CancellationToken cancellationToken
);
```

Where as `IActionFilter` (which `ActionFilterAttribute` implements) has a slightly extended signature:

```
Task<HttpResponseMessage> ExecuteActionFilterAsync(
    HttpActionContext actionContext,
    CancellationToken cancellationToken,
    Func<Task<HttpResponseMessage>> continuation
);
```

The big difference here is the `Func<Task<HttpResponseMessage>> continuation` that is passed in. Personally, I theorize that this is passed in as the sum of filter actions that have been decorated based on the following line `OrchardApiActionFilterDispatcher`:

```
continuation = () => actionFilter.ExecuteActionFilterAsync(
    actionContext, cancellationToken, continuation
);
```

Consequently, it appears to enter a filter and call continutaion() from within the filter. Digging right down through some private methods in `ActionFilterAttribute` we ultimately find:

```
HttpResponseMessage response = await continutaion();
```

Seeing as this is the stack of all filter calls, calling this essentially calls the top of the filter stack again and makes the same call to the filter that was just made. This continues ad-infinitum until we end up with a stack overflow.

Does anyone at Orchard (or out in the world of StackOverflow) have any ideas on this matter? Are we simply using these filter incorrectly? Have we missed something? Or is this just a bug that needs addressing?